# Read a connection string from a XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I've read about all I could get on how to read from an XML file, but I can't get anything done. I want to read a connectionstring from an XML file, plain and simple, nothing more.

My XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<connectionString>  
    <conn>"adsf"</conn>
</connectionString>
```

And I've tried varios way with

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlLoc);

while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
{
    XmlNode a = doc.ReadNode(reader);
    textBox1.Text = Text + a.Name;
}

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlLoc); //myXmlString is the xml file in string //copying xml to string: string myXmlString = xmldoc.OuterXml.ToString();
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/connectionString");

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    XmlNode example = xn.SelectSingleNode("conn");

    if (example != null)
    {
        string na = example["Name"].InnerText;
        string no = example["NO"].InnerText;
    }
}
```

I'm missing something and I'm not sure what, this should be a very simple task, but I can't get it done. Any help?

I'm trying to do it in a WIndows form application program.

Comment: why don't you use .net's built in facilities for app.config?

Comment: Is this your `app.config` file?

Comment: @DanielA.White becouse I'm kinda new to visual studion and C#. I could use app.config with no problems, but I would need some clear steps on what to do, whatever I found untill now couldn't get me to the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm missing something?

Yes. .NET has a built in mechanism for storing your connection string, inside an `App.config` file, there is no reason to manually store it and parse it yourself.

Right click your project, go to Add -> New Item

Then, add a "Application Configuration File":

[image: Application Configuration File]

Once it opens, add a `connectionStrings` node to it, as follows:

```
// This is an example of a connectionString node. You may add child
// values to it as follows
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="YourConnectionStringKey" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
             connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then, you access it using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`:

```
string connectionString = 
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringKey"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: What do I have to add for ConfigurationManager? It doesn't find the reference. Error 1 The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @CiucaS You'll need to add reference to `System.Configuration.dll`

Comment: I only have ansamblies and Internal

Comment: @CiucaS I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't have System.Configuration.DLL ony .Ansamblies and .Internal

Comment: What type of project template are you using? Class library?

Comment: It's a WFA and it's a form.

Comment: there seem to be a problem with NETFramework 4.5, i can't add System.Configuration.DLL on my project. No idea why.

Comment: Never mind i was trying to add System.Configuration.DLL not System.Configuration only.

Comment: "There is no reason to manually store it and parse it yourself", Yes there is, what is you want different config files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq to xml.

```
var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText("fileName.xml");


var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);

var result = str.Elements("word").
Where(x => x.Element("connectionString").Value.Equals("conn"));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This might work (or may be some changes you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = XElement.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""yes""?><connectionString><conn>adsf</conn></connectionString>");
// or var x = XElement.Load(@"c:\temp\my.xml");
var s = x.Element("conn").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you still have not found your answer then try this (a bit old school but it worked for me)

public class Common
    {
        public Common()
        {
        }
//      public static string GetXML()
//      {
//          return @"C:\MyLocation\Connections.xml";
//      }
        public static string GetXMLconn(string strConn)
        {
            string xmlConStr = "";
            //
            string XMLconn = @"C:\Mylocation\Connections.xml"; 

            // Get the Connection String from the XML file.
            XmlTextReader textReader  = new XmlTextReader(XMLconn);
            textReader.Read();
            while (textReader.Read())
            {
                // Read the currect element in the loop
                textReader.MoveToElement();
                // If the element name is correct then read and assign the connection string
                if (textReader.Name == strConn)
                {
                    xmlConStr = textReader.ReadString();
                }
            }
            textReader.Close();

            return xmlConStr;

        }

}
```