# Unable to get ConnectionString value from Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, configurationmanager

I do not know why am I getting this error I have tried everything but I am still getting this error again and again. Any help which would solve this problem will be appreciated.

Here is the error:

[image]

Connection string in `web.config`:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi @MarkJordan, welcome to StackOverflow, please ensure your config file's ConnectionString section contains this ConnectionString.

Comment: @YongShun NO the question you suggested is not relevant for my problem.

Comment: @YongShun do you mean to make a ConnectionString in Web.config

Comment: @YongShun I have already done as you said but I am still getting this error don't know why?

Comment: Hi @Mark, I see you put connectionStrings section in **w**eb.config, please move it to outer **W**eb.config. This will solve your issue.

Comment: @YongShun that's done the job thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the extension to the solution which I mentioned in the question's comment:

### EXPLANATION

According to the article [Tale of two web.config in MVC](https://blog.jsinh.in/man-002-tale-of-two-web-config-in-mvc/),

> web.config in **View folder**

Implemented for **blocking access to view folder and files directly via user request or through URL**.

> Web.config in **project folder**

Where all the `appSettings`, `connectionStrings`, `configSections` and [etc.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_configuration.htm) are configured here and these settings/values are able to be accessible for the entire project.

---

### SOLUTION

Thus, you need to **move the `<ConnectionStrings>` section from web.config (in the root of the View folder) to Web.config (in the root of the project folder)**.

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues, but the main one is that you are getting null, why are you getting null? Because that's what you get after reading your settings file. So basically, the problem is that you are reading null from settings file, if you are passing correctly the configuration, that is, the settings file.

That's what I would do,

When debugging, see the Configuration Manager, try to see what you have attached to it and it's values, then, it is easy to figure out what it should be.

I think your problem is in the ConfigurationManager, in fact, you should use more the breakpoints and the watch.

Have a look at [Read a connection string from a XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329458/read-a-connection-string-from-a-xml-file), to see how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

please set like this

```
string ConnectionString =
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"];
```

this will work